# How to solve an installation problem involving QGIS, Python, and a plug-in?

Tags: python, qgis

In an attempt to get the plugin "Profile Tool" working, I installed geoslib and python Shapely 1.2.10 module as requested using following:

```
sudo port install geos
```

Then install Shapely once downloaded:

```
python setup.py install
```

Now whenever I load a Python plugin in QGIS, the whole app crashes. Loading with "--noplugins" or deleting plugins from ~/.qgis is the only way to get QGIS to load.

I suspect I have messed up the Python installation. Which version of Python should QGIS being using? The version in /usr/bin/python or does it come with its own version?

From within QGIS, the python console displays path as:

```
>>> import sys
```

> > > sys.path
> > >       ['/Applications/GIS/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python', '/Users/jon/.qgis/python', '/Users/jon/.qgis/python/plugins', '/Applications/GIS/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins', '/Library/Frameworks/SQLite3.framework/Versions/3/Python', '/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.8/Python/site-packages', '/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/Shapely-1.2.10-py2.6.egg', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python26.zip', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-darwin', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-mac', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-tk', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-old', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload', '/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/wx-2.8-mac-unicode', '/Applications/GIS/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python/plugins/fTools/tools']

Crash log below.

Any help greatly appreciated. I am stuck with a non-functioning QGIS app and can't do much at the minute without some plugins.

```
    Process:         QGIS [1320]
Path:            /Applications/GIS/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/QGIS
Identifier:      org.qgis.qgis
Version:         1.7.0 (1.7.0-Wroclaw (exported))
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [227]

Date/Time:       2011-08-15 17:12:28.401 +1000
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.6.8 (10K540)
Report Version:  6
Sleep/Wake UUID: 6C49B351-8735-4919-8292-F2C1CEE58FFB

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Thread 0 Crashed:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   ???                              000000000000000000 0 + 0
1   org.python.python                0x000000011bb9fd3b _PyImport_LoadDynamicModule + 189
2   org.python.python                0x000000011bb9eaf8 PyImport_ReloadModule + 1347
3   org.python.python                0x000000011bb9ef78 PyImport_ReloadModule + 2499
4   org.python.python                0x000000011bb9f59a PyImport_ImportModuleLevel + 1265
5   org.python.python                0x000000011bb879cb _PyBuiltin_Init + 14264
6   org.python.python                0x000000011bb8d187 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 15317
7   org.python.python                0x000000011bb8ecce PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1803
8   org.python.python                0x000000011bb308e1 PyClassMethod_New + 1748
9   org.python.python                0x000000011bb0eff3 PyObject_Call + 112
10  org.python.python                0x000000011bb889db PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords + 175
11  org.python.python                0x000000011bb8c5ea PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 12344
12  org.python.python                0x000000011bb8ecce PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1803
13  org.python.python                0x000000011bb8ed61 PyEval_EvalCode + 54
14  org.python.python                0x000000011bb9c8f2 PyImport_ExecCodeModuleEx + 258
15  org.python.python                0x000000011bb9d248 PyImport_AppendInittab + 1026
16  org.python.python                0x000000011bb9e1d0 _PyImport_FindModule + 379
17  org.python.python                0x000000011bb9eaf8 PyImport_ReloadModule + 1347
18  org.python.python                0x000000011bb9ef78 PyImport_ReloadModule + 2499
19  org.python.python                0x000000011bb9f59a PyImport_ImportModuleLevel + 1265
20  org.python.python                0x000000011bb879cb _PyBuiltin_Init + 14264
21  org.python.python                0x000000011bb8d187 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 15317
22  org.python.python                0x000000011bb8ecce PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1803
23  org.python.python                0x000000011bb308e1 PyClassMethod_New + 1748
24  org.python.python                0x000000011bb0eff3 PyObject_Call + 112
25  org.python.python                0x000000011bb889db PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords + 175
26  org.python.python                0x000000011bb8c5ea PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 12344
27  org.python.python                0x000000011bb8ecce PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1803
28  org.python.python                0x000000011bb8ed61 PyEval_EvalCode + 54
29  org.python.python                0x000000011bb9c8f2 PyImport_ExecCodeModuleEx + 258
30  org.python.python                0x000000011bb9d248 PyImport_AppendInittab + 1026
31  org.python.python                0x000000011bb9eaf8 PyImport_ReloadModule + 1347
32  org.python.python                0x000000011bb9ef78 PyImport_ReloadModule + 2499
33  org.python.python                0x000000011bb9f56a PyImport_ImportModuleLevel + 1217
34  org.python.python                0x000000011bb879cb _PyBuiltin_Init + 14264
35  org.python.python                0x000000011bb8d187 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 15317
36  org.python.python                0x000000011bb8ecce PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1803
37  org.python.python                0x000000011bb308e1 PyClassMethod_New + 1748
38  org.python.python                0x000000011bb0eff3 PyObject_Call + 112
39  org.python.python                0x000000011bb889db PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords + 175
40  org.python.python                0x000000011bb8c5ea PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 12344
41  org.python.python                0x000000011bb8ecce PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1803
42  org.python.python                0x000000011bb8ed61 PyEval_EvalCode + 54
43  org.python.python                0x000000011bb9c8f2 PyImport_ExecCodeModuleEx + 258
44  org.python.python                0x000000011bb9d248 PyImport_AppendInittab + 1026
45  org.python.python                0x000000011bb9eaf8 PyImport_ReloadModule + 1347
46  org.python.python                0x000000011bb9ef78 PyImport_ReloadModule + 2499
47  org.python.python                0x000000011bb9f56a PyImport_ImportModuleLevel + 1217
48  org.python.python                0x000000011bb879cb _PyBuiltin_Init + 14264
49  org.python.python                0x000000011bb8d187 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 15317
50  org.python.python                0x000000011bb8ecce PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1803
51  org.python.python                0x000000011bb308e1 PyClassMethod_New + 1748
52  org.python.python                0x000000011bb0eff3 PyObject_Call + 112
53  org.python.python                0x000000011bb889db PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords + 175
54  org.python.python                0x000000011bb8c5ea PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 12344
55  org.python.python                0x000000011bb8d2e1 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 15663
56  org.python.python                0x000000011bb8ecce PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1803
57  org.python.python                0x000000011bb8ed61 PyEval_EvalCode + 54
58  org.python.python                0x000000011bba665a Py_CompileString + 78
59  org.python.python                0x000000011bba6805 PyRun_StringFlags + 119
60  org.python.python                0x000000011bb8b4ca PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 7960
61  org.python.python                0x000000011bb8ecce PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1803
62  org.python.python                0x000000011bb8d35e PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 15788
63  org.python.python                0x000000011bb8d2e1 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 15663
64  org.python.python                0x000000011bb8d2e1 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 15663
65  org.python.python                0x000000011bb8d2e1 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 15663
66  org.python.python                0x000000011bb8ecce PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1803
67  org.python.python                0x000000011bb8ed61 PyEval_EvalCode + 54
68  org.python.python                0x000000011bba665a Py_CompileString + 78
69  org.python.python                0x000000011bba6805 PyRun_StringFlags + 119
70  libqgispython.1.7.0.dylib        0x000000011bafe496 QgsPythonUtilsImpl::evalString(QString const&, QString&) + 122
71  libqgispython.1.7.0.dylib        0x000000011bafdd21 QgsPythonUtilsImpl::startPlugin(QString) + 111
72  org.qgis.qgis                    0x0000000100110dc6 QgsPluginRegistry::loadPythonPlugin(QString) + 496
73  org.qgis.qgis                    0x00000001001129f7 QgsPluginRegistry::restoreSessionPlugins(QString) + 2193
74  org.qgis.qgis                    0x000000010002ae6e QgisApp::QgisApp(QSplashScreen*, bool, QWidget*, QFlags<Qt::WindowType>) + 3050
75  org.qgis.qgis                    0x0000000100012057 main + 7683
76  org.qgis.qgis                    0x000000010000feac start + 52

Thread 1:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libSystem.B.dylib                0x00007fff8585ac0a kevent + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib                0x00007fff8585cadd _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 154
2   libSystem.B.dylib                0x00007fff8585c7b4 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 185
3   libSystem.B.dylib                0x00007fff8585c2de _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 252
4   libSystem.B.dylib                0x00007fff8585bc08 _pthread_wqthread + 353
5   libSystem.B.dylib                0x00007fff8585baa5 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib                0x00007fff8585ba2a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib                0x00007fff8585be3c _pthread_wqthread + 917
2   libSystem.B.dylib                0x00007fff8585baa5 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 3:
0   libSystem.B.dylib                0x00007fff8585ba2a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib                0x00007fff8585be3c _pthread_wqthread + 917
2   libSystem.B.dylib                0x00007fff8585baa5 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 4:
0   libSystem.B.dylib                0x00007fff8585ba2a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib                0x00007fff8585be3c _pthread_wqthread + 917
2   libSystem.B.dylib                0x00007fff8585baa5 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x000000011fd5b840  rbx: 0x000000011f740408  rcx: 0x0000000000000b31  rdx: 0x000000011fd5b840
  rdi: 0x000000011bc9ed00  rsi: 0x000000011f740730  rbp: 0x00007fff5fbf80b0  rsp: 0x00007fff5fbf8098
   r8: 0x0000000000000000   r9: 0x000000011cb84ad0  r10: 0x000000011cb7afe0  r11: 0x000000011bb3fe7d
  r12: 0x000000011bc9ed00  r13: 0x0000000000000000  r14: 0x00007fff5fbf8630  r15: 0x00007fff5fbf8150
  rip: 0x0000000000000000  rfl: 0x0000000000010246  cr2: 0x0000000000000000

Binary Images:
       0x100000000 -        0x100491fff +org.qgis.qgis 1.7.0 (1.7.0-Wroclaw (exported)) <1D91FB61-31DA-06DE-DA64-5AB29A3C5F07> /Applications/GIS/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/QGIS
       0x1005ee000 -        0x10067bff7 +libqwt.dylib 5.2.1 (compatibility 5.2.0) <A4BDC10C-06CC-D7B8-BEB8-0037CEDEA165> /Applications/GIS/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/libqwt.dylib
       0x1006cc000 -        0x100703fff +QtSql 4.7.3 (compatibility 4.7.0) <F5B9EBFD-65ED-35D6-26E3-769F1E0DEF2B> /Applications/GIS/QGIS.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtSql.framework/Versions/4/QtSql
       0x10071a000 -        0x10096cfe7 +libqgis_core.1.7.0.dylib 1.7.0 (compatibility 1.7.0) <9FC26325-F285-0791-0D3E-2F4AE77DC454> /Applications/GIS/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/libqgis_core.1.7.0.dylib
       0x100a5f000 -        0x100bc9ff7 +libqgis_gui.1.7.0.dylib 1.7.0 (compatibility 1.7.0) <15EC96DB-4381-4023-CA0F-EEAD93420BA6> /Applications/GIS/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/libqgis_gui.1.7.0.dylib
       0x100c7e000 -        0x100cbffef +libqgis_analysis.1.7.0.dylib 1.7.0 (compatibility 1.7.0) <85BFF9C9-A84F-D989-75E3-C803CA5B5C37> /Applications/GIS/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/libqgis_analysis.1.7.0.dylib
       0x100cd9000 -        0x100cf5fff +libpq.dylib 5.3.0 (compatibility 5.0.0) <1FB622DB-BAB7-F4CD-D9A9-7E024478EBB7> /Applications/GIS/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/libpq.dylib
       0x100cff000 -        0x10105cfff +org.sqlite.sqlite3 3.7.4 (SQLite3 3.7.4-2) <C90C1409-CAD8-8662-6047-667AA6108EB8> /Library/Frameworks/SQLite3.framework/Versions/3/SQLite3
       0x10107b000 -        0x1010b8fff +QtXml 4.7.3 (compatibility 4.7.0) <811907C3-6FE0-EA37-67F0-8BE955F0BA1B> /Applications/GIS/QGIS.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtXml.framework/Versions/4/QtXml
       0x1010d2000 -        0x10135aff7 +QtCore 4.7.3 (compatibility 4.7.0) <1A2CF13B-BB74-85EA-5A4D-1C477E02DF6E> /Applications/GIS/QGIS.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/QtCore
       0x1013ee000 -        0x101dcbff7 +QtGui 4.7.3 (compatibility 4.7.0) <1F568542-C5A4-8A3C-5006-EA65FEDE23F6> /Applications/GIS/QGIS.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/QtGui
       0x102075000 -        0x10219cff7 +QtNetwork 4.7.3 (compatibility 4.7.0) <691D3311-87BE-C23E-49F3-FC300D428C61> /Applications/GIS/QGIS.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/4/QtNetwork
       0x1021f5000 -        0x102244fef +QtSvg 4.7.3 (compatibility 4.7.0) <A7789926-A9A6-9BE3-4C11-E8D58E816DFC> /Applications/GIS/QGIS.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtSvg.framework/Versions/4/QtSvg
       0x102265000 -        0x102294fff +org.maptools.proj 4.7.0 (PROJ 4.7.0-2) <7FCE23B7-503C-8C93-6BD2-5D08C5B262DB> /Library/Frameworks/PROJ.framework/Versions/4/PROJ
       0x1022a0000 -        0x1023abfff +org.osgeo.geos 3.3.0 (GEOS 3.3.0-1) <BF9394BA-B8CD-4150-250A-98A38060BEB8> /Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/Versions/3/GEOS
       0x102506000 -        0x103265fe7 +org.gdal.gdal 1.8.0 (GDAL/OGR 1.8.0-2) <92C8A957-8799-F90E-FC59-05DE1B59FCA6> /Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.8/GDAL
       0x10388a000 -        0x1038cdff7  libiodbc.2.dylib 4.18.0 (compatibility 4.0.0) <9E10F33D-B573-3B98-E756-392037B9229E> /usr/lib/libiodbc.2.dylib
       0x1038d8000 -        0x1038e6fff  libiodbcinst.2.dylib 4.18.0 (compatibility 4.0.0) <32500035-5777-D45C-E5AD-54A5D0C4F461> /usr/lib/libiodbcinst.2.dylib
       0x1038ec000 -        0x1039f9fef +com.kyngchaos.UnixImageIO 1.3.0 (UnixImageIO 1.3.0) <9F2021D8-AA8A-DD27-0BFB-96335704C28E> /Library/Frameworks/UnixImageIO.framework/Versions/D/UnixImageIO
       0x103a31000 -        0x103a69fe7 +libogdi.dylib ??? (???) <F2BF367E-21A2-CEC2-1B5B-64E0508DBB1F> /Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.8/Libraries/libogdi.dylib
       0x103a75000 -        0x103a7dfef +libintl.dylib 10.1.0 (compatibility 10.0.0) <937F7B46-EC9C-4441-43FD-4CD508BE99E2> /Applications/GIS/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/libintl.dylib
       0x103cc3000 -        0x103cd0fff +com.rogueamoeba.audio_hijack_server.hermes 2.2.8 (2.2.8) <DBE64033-014D-0508-024D-EE1BDA4C8528> /usr/local/hermes/modules/Instant Hijack Server.hermesmodule/Contents/MacOS/Instant Hijack Server
       0x103ffa000 -        0x103ffbff7  _functools.so ??? (???) <97A294C7-290C-9746-B294-275516490F40> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/_functools.so
       0x11675b000 -        0x116796ff7 +libqjpeg.dylib ??? (???) <2D99F9D4-B313-6024-82E7-42B9EB233A47> /Applications/GIS/QGIS.app/Contents/PlugIns/imageformats/libqjpeg.dylib
       0x11679f000 -        0x1167acfff +libcoordinatecaptureplugin.so ??? (???) <38B5DF22-D8D7-16FF-44C1-0DA3BA3E0BF7> /Applications/GIS/QGIS.app/Contents/PlugIns/qgis/libcoordinatecaptureplugin.so
       0x1167b5000 -        0x1167c1fff +libcopyrightlabelplugin.so ??? (???) <659E091F-9BCD-47DC-7A04-1FA7B197D9DC> /Applications/GIS/QGIS.app/Contents/PlugIns/qgis/libcopyrightlabelplugin.so
       0x1167fa000 -        0x1167fbfff  cStringIO.so ??? (???) <0C7D1D15-4241-99A9-7671-A3CF105C2EBB> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/cStringIO.so
       0x116ed6000 -        0x116ee9ff7 +libdelimitedtextplugin.so ??? (???) <4C8C4C33-BDB6-663A-381B-4AE3B9F766B0> /Applications/GIS/QGIS.app/Contents/PlugIns/qgis/libdelimitedtextplugin.so
       0x116ef3000 -        0x116ef5ff7  math.so ??? (???) <54D066FD-A9F9-EA69-8C3C-CE83DF68C58A> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/math.so
       0x116efb000 -        0x116efcfff  _random.so ??? (???) <FC54824D-3F1F-D538-DBF8-05E393A696B6> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/_random.so
       0x117f80000 -        0x117f8cfef +libdelimitedtextprovider.so ??? (???) <7344FDA8-1F61-8093-6087-B970C1B3601A> /Applications/GIS/QGIS.app/Contents/PlugIns/qgis/libdelimitedtextprovider.so
       0x117f94000 -        0x117fb7ff7 +libdiagramoverlay.so ??? (???) <0C636064-256B-F93C-9D28-86EC28330DFC> /Applications/GIS/QGIS.app/Contents/PlugIns/qgis/libdiagramoverlay.so
       0x117fcf000 -        0x117fe3ff7 +libdisplacementplugin.so ??? (???) <003F036F-251B-DB07-E119-4AEA19C2075B> /Applications/GIS/QGIS.app/Contents/PlugIns/qgis/libdisplacementplugin.so
       0x117ff2000 -        0x117ff5fff +_gdalconst.so ??? (???) <20E606D9-4BB8-8821-CC78-C31B17CC804C> /Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.8/Python/site-packages/osgeo/_gdalconst.so
       0x117ff9000 -        0x117ffbfe7  binascii.so ??? (???) <D7D60C49-DEFA-5DB1-83B0-F91347966BC8> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/binascii.so
       0x119461000 -        0x119482fef +libdxf2shpconverterplugin.so ??? (???) <E210C964-F20A-0C79-8E18-BD4A2EB79A99> /Applications/GIS/QGIS.app/Contents/PlugIns/qgis/libdxf2shpconverterplugin.so
       0x119494000 -        0x1194c9fef +libevis.so ??? (???) <F818705D-59FA-A057-6B4A-4E2C8101D81D> /Applications/GIS/QGIS.app/Contents/PlugIns/qgis/libevis.so
       0x1194e0000 -        0x1194f1ff7 +libgdalprovider.so ??? (???) <E4501494-A2FD-D14A-C63E-B5515D10EE6F> /Applications/GIS/QGIS.app/Contents/PlugIns/qgis/libgdalprovider.so
       0x1194fb000 -        0x11956bfff +libgeorefplugin.so ??? (???) <5183AEB7-CBA0-AC52-104F-DF4127CD45F4> /Applications/GIS/QGIS.app/Contents/PlugIns/qgis/libgeorefplugin.so
       0x11959d000 -        0x11971cfef +org.gnu.gsl 1.14 (GSL 1.14-1) <7A5D6DBB-2673-BE9B-EA2A-5FA502828B83> /Library/Frameworks/GSL.framework/Versions/1/GSL
       0x119775000 -        0x119778fff  _csv.so ??? (???) <ACE39A2B-E3BC-EC0C-D825-1812240F2B06> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/_csv.so
       0x11b701000 -        0x11b730fe7 +libgpsimporterplugin.so ??? (???) <3B10A0BE-C0F2-1B82-40A5-A945F309E882> /Applications/GIS/QGIS.app/Contents/PlugIns/qgis/libgpsimporterplugin.so
       0x11b742000 -        0x11b758fe7 +libgpxprovider.so ??? (???) <7D83BB8A-090F-92BA-AD8F-5727FA698EAA> /Applications/GIS/QGIS.app/Contents/PlugIns/qgis/libgpxprovider.so
       0x11b767000 -        0x11b77bff7 +libinterpolationplugin.so ??? (???) <519BF936-025C-4D4B-BA9F-1AFC827A3C5B> /Applications/GIS/QGIS.app/Contents/PlugIns/qgis/libinterpolationplugin.so
       0x11b789000 -        0x11b795fff +libmemoryprovider.so ??? (???) <1ADC4FEA-C6C9-4F36-EDFA-72123FC375E7> /Applications/GIS/QGIS.app/Contents/PlugIns/qgis/libmemoryprovider.so
       0x11b79e000 -        0x11b7abfe7 +libnortharrowplugin.so ??? (???) <83F8A703-C231-D010-FEA4-A538337BA922> /Applications/GIS/QGIS.app/Contents/PlugIns/qgis/libnortharrowplugin.so
       0x11b7b5000 -        0x11b7d3fe7 +libofflineeditingplugin.so ??? (???) <48F67327-1A7C-3268-98E9-C8B3BAE3EDE9> /Applications/GIS/QGIS.app/Contents/PlugIns/qgis/libofflineeditingplugin.so
       0x11b7e5000 -        0x11b800ff7 +libogrprovider.so ??? (???) <444694DF-5A9C-42D5-E0EC-8E05046F16C7> /Applications/GIS/QGIS.app/Contents/PlugIns/qgis/libogrprovider.so
       0x11b80d000 -        0x11b81efef +liboracleplugin.so ??? (???) <5C7297D3-EBD5-1573-DFDD-3C81DB9A2782> /Applications/GIS/QGIS.app/Contents/PlugIns/qgis/liboracleplugin.so
       0x11b828000 -        0x11b847fef +libosmprovider.so ??? (???) <87F44AF8-B191-C2F5-BA78-0F11584787EB> /Applications/GIS/QGIS.app/Contents/PlugIns/qgis/libosmprovider.so
       0x11b857000 -        0x11b894fe7 +libpostgresprovider.so ??? (???) <D6F01231-8B79-963F-9E8D-0E58BCF9178A> /Applications/GIS/QGIS.app/Contents/PlugIns/qgis/libpostgresprovider.so
       0x11b8a5000 -        0x11b8b1fef +librasterterrainplugin.so ??? (???) <5F8F4162-E5B0-DA3B-7747-DFBEBABFD1B3> /Applications/GIS/QGIS.app/Contents/PlugIns/qgis/librasterterrainplugin.so
       0x11b8ba000 -        0x11b8dcff7 +libroadgraphplugin.so ??? (???) <8852024C-6520-BBDC-DC11-19DA4EDB56C0> /Applications/GIS/QGIS.app/Contents/PlugIns/qgis/libroadgraphplugin.so
       0x11b8f3000 -        0x11b901fff +libscalebarplugin.so ??? (???) <C2070C09-CD50-B394-F7BF-E940C76A29A3> /Applications/GIS/QGIS.app/Contents/PlugIns/qgis/libscalebarplugin.so
       0x11b90b000 -        0x11b92bfef +libspatialiteprovider.so ??? (???) <7DCD0C0C-EFC4-89E4-C027-60AD5D24CBC6> /Applications/GIS/QGIS.app/Contents/PlugIns/qgis/libspatialiteprovider.so
       0x11b936000 -        0x11b953fff +libspatialqueryplugin.so ??? (???) <10E21ED9-FEEC-9E88-28D0-E3072EEE4E2E> /Applications/GIS/QGIS.app/Contents/PlugIns/qgis/libspatialqueryplugin.so
       0x11b964000 -        0x11b9b3fef +libspitplugin.so ??? (???) <D729BCBF-BE8A-7A18-C3DB-B5A7D8C1689D> /Applications/GIS/QGIS.app/Contents/PlugIns/qgis/libspitplugin.so
       0x11b9c6000 -        0x11b9f4fe7 +libsqlanywhereplugin.so ??? (???) <12FC3AA4-E9EE-7E27-6825-1BBAB532ED6C> /Applications/GIS/QGIS.app/Contents/PlugIns/qgis/libsqlanywhereplugin.so
       0x11ba0c000 -        0x11ba1aff7 +libqgissqlanyconnection.1.7.0.dylib 1.7.0 (compatibility 1.7.0) <49430729-C774-59EE-AC9F-AE6A2EC92C1A> /Applications/GIS/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/libqgissqlanyconnection.1.7.0.dylib
       0x11ba20000 -        0x11ba3efef +libsqlanywhereprovider.so ??? (???) <F74D1F73-A392-74BF-046E-D68CB47C482C> /Applications/GIS/QGIS.app/Contents/PlugIns/qgis/libsqlanywhereprovider.so
       0x11ba49000 -        0x11ba6dfef +libwfsplugin.so ??? (???) <2E749ABF-A44F-D28F-92F5-A74EE81C74B2> /Applications/GIS/QGIS.app/Contents/PlugIns/qgis/libwfsplugin.so
       0x11ba7e000 -        0x11baa7fff +libwfsprovider.so ??? (???) <1FD25BE5-6AA6-6FEB-144A-3AB15D99ACBD> /Applications/GIS/QGIS.app/Contents/PlugIns/qgis/libwfsprovider.so
       0x11bab9000 -        0x11bae8fe7 +libwmsprovider.so ??? (???) <E98A3441-B816-DC87-0CCB-39F74406627A> /Applications/GIS/QGIS.app/Contents/PlugIns/qgis/libwmsprovider.so
       0x11baf8000 -        0x11bb03ff7 +libqgispython.1.7.0.dylib 1.7.0 (compatibility 1.7.0) <F590EC1D-0215-D020-0BBA-00EE88F142C7> /Applications/GIS/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/libqgispython.1.7.0.dylib
       0x11bb08000 -        0x11bc18ff7  org.python.python 2.6.1 (2.6.1) <126DA8FF-5BC2-8788-51E3-D7A29A3F9F0F> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Python
       0x11bd68000 -        0x11bd7bfef +sip.so ??? (???) <A207F0A4-B4B2-A7C3-54FB-CC2A0EE2CAEC> /Applications/GIS/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python/sip.so
       0x11bd84000 -        0x11bf25fe7 +QtCore.so ??? (???) <BFB7B36F-C825-98EE-3ECE-DD72A17DF992> /Applications/GIS/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python/PyQt4/QtCore.so
       0x11c0f9000 -        0x11c0faff7  time.so ??? (???) <80513398-F49E-79D1-5014-514361869D40> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/time.so
       0x11c200000 -        0x11c719ff7 +QtGui.so ??? (???) <9DD97B5D-46EA-89A8-F4B2-C7E0C0E24FF1> /Applications/GIS/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python/PyQt4/QtGui.so
       0x11cae1000 -        0x11cae6fff  itertools.so ??? (???) <9287854F-7F2B-D4AF-FCA3-EB69DA821DA9> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/itertools.so
       0x11caee000 -        0x11caf1ff7  strop.so ??? (???) <4A91CDB0-6E91-DA0E-8E6B-38BE29105EA0> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/strop.so
       0x11caf6000 -        0x11cafaff7  _struct.so ??? (???) <B4DD710D-1511-99F0-66AE-329185E2B88C> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/_struct.so
       0x11cc00000 -        0x11cd81ff7 +core.so ??? (???) <50F0DE0C-1095-D401-4D07-A4D41D35F0E8> /Applications/GIS/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python/qgis/core.so
       0x11ce87000 -        0x11cef9fef +QtNetwork.so ??? (???) <B7A8946F-0C04-7A26-986F-771060CFCF25> /Applications/GIS/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python/PyQt4/QtNetwork.so
       0x11cf51000 -        0x11cf87fff +QtXml.so ??? (???) <0E038330-445A-CFCD-9999-ECF0792C36BD> /Applications/GIS/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python/PyQt4/QtXml.so
       0x11cff1000 -        0x11cff4ff7  zlib.so ??? (???) <647721E3-67B5-8CD0-3A78-060FF9C80924> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/zlib.so
       0x11cff9000 -        0x11cffafff +Qt.so ??? (???) <7FA143FB-1433-4AB0-7E5B-05A5A912637F> /Applications/GIS/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python/PyQt4/Qt.so
       0x11d100000 -        0x11d1e0fff +gui.so ??? (???) <E6263E74-A069-A45D-502D-D7AB4D2EE335> /Applications/GIS/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python/qgis/gui.so
       0x11d27d000 -        0x11d2c5fe7 +QtWebKit.so ??? (???) <3068F58D-058F-4AA8-28B1-A1ABF5323755> /Applications/GIS/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python/PyQt4/QtWebKit.so
       0x11d2ff000 -        0x11e5b4fe7 +QtWebKit 4.7.3 (compatibility 4.7.0) <0722A3F1-7C5D-2DE4-B431-8DF4587AF8B5> /Applications/GIS/QGIS.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtWebKit.framework/Versions/4/QtWebKit
       0x11ed4f000 -        0x11ed97fef +phonon 4.4.0 (compatibility 4.4.0) <BB166737-664C-0BA3-684B-55C8E936958A> /Applications/GIS/QGIS.app/Contents/Frameworks/phonon.framework/Versions/4/phonon
       0x11edbe000 -        0x11ee3dff7 +QtDBus 4.7.3 (compatibility 4.7.0) <2082C4C0-0173-10A0-512B-1F4ACDD65F2E> /Applications/GIS/QGIS.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtDBus.framework/Versions/4/QtDBus
       0x11ee61000 -        0x11eea8ff7 +_gdal.so ??? (???) <326CAECE-6D5A-E600-EA6B-FB05F31C771F> /Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.8/Python/site-packages/osgeo/_gdal.so
       0x11eefa000 -        0x11efe0ff7 +gdal_ECW_JP2ECW.dylib ??? (???) <3D045D3F-3501-BA5F-2156-7E903351CF15> /Library/Application Support/GDAL/1.8/PlugIns/gdal_ECW_JP2ECW.dylib
       0x11f08f000 -        0x11f0daff7 +_ogr.so ??? (???) <B78AB528-01A1-7056-FA76-7D933CDFB486> /Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.8/Python/site-packages/osgeo/_ogr.so
       0x11f0e9000 -        0x11f0f4fe7  datetime.so ??? (???) <C8DD63B4-9685-C134-E60A-0ED11A0CCAF7> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/datetime.so
       0x11f240000 -        0x11f274fff +_osr.so ??? (???) <D4B2287A-3AD5-90FA-8422-D515ECAF0A5B> /Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.8/Python/site-packages/osgeo/_osr.so
       0x11f5bf000 -        0x11f5c8fff  _sqlite3.so ??? (???) <9FBFA469-EEA4-67CA-B92D-5C30D91887E9> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so
       0x11f5d2000 -        0x11f64ffef  unicodedata.so ??? (???) <27EF63BF-90E9-3D71-FE24-1EA634E99498> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/unicodedata.so
       0x11f7e4000 -        0x11f7f1fff  _sort.so ??? (???) <AC4F6F41-7C43-A370-7044-4DF77A34C674> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/numpy/core/_sort.so
```

etc
etc

Answer (score 2):

if you delete a particular plugin from .qgis and then QGIS works then I would say that the problem is in the 3rd party plugin, not QGIS. Drop a note the plugin author.